# What is "חכמת לב"?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, mishkan-tabernacle, vayakhel

In this week's Torah portion (Vayakhel) we read about the Jews helping out in the building of the Tabernacle. When [referring](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9896#v=25) to the talent (or mastery) in doing so, the Torah uses the term "חכמת לב". To me this seems like an unusual term to describe talent. Is there anything deeper here? or this is actually a typical term?

Comment: Ibn Ezra's explanation sounds credible. My own thinking, based on a "simpler" level - The center of emotions is in the heart. Often, when we do a job, we have the wisdom and knowledge of how to do it, but inevitably our emotions can inhibit or enhance what we do. Thus, in the building of the mishkan, these were people who used their emotional "wisdom" to enhance their work. It's one thing to do what's needed. But to make it nice and extraordinary requires the wisdom of the heart, not just from the brain.

Comment: The Chumash often uses לב/לבב to mean "mind". This is evident from many instances (and discussed at length by R. Shlomo Fisher in Beis Yishai)

Answer (score 2):

Ibn Ezra [writes](http://www.sefaria.org/Ibn_Ezra_on_Exodus.31.6.2?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) (to [Shmos 31:6](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9892#v=6)):

> **ובלב כל חכם לב.** לעשות מלאכה כי גם זה ימצא בתולדת האדם שיוציא מלבו דברים עמוקים במלאכת המדות והוא לא למד החכמה
>
> **and all the wise hearted into whose hearts I have instilled wisdom** -- to do work; for we find a similar thing among people, who know how to do complicated (lit. deep) things, even as they have not learned that
>   wisdom themselves.

(*my translation*)

This would seem to imply that "חכמי לב" refer to those who did the skilled labor in the Mishkan without being taught how to do it, but rather knew how to do it intuitively, with Hashem's help.

Almost whenever this idea was brought up, the speaker would mention that this actually makes a lot of sense -- after all, do we really expect that a nation of one time slaves, who were forced to do "back-breaking labor" ([Shmos 1:14](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9862#v=14)), would really have been taught by their masters to weave and work with gold and silver, and all of the other skilled labors that were needed for the Mishkan?

Comment: that's a nice pshat, but i'm asking something different. what is actual terminology being used here. what does a heart or wisdom have to do with being a skilled craftsman?

Comment: Having a heart of wisdom, according to Ibn Ezra, means that they had skilled knowledge without training...at least, that's how I read it.

Comment: I hope the feminists out there don't jump down my throat for this, but some of the Israelite women HAD to be skilled weavers.  Who made all their clothes?  The men?

Answer (score 0):

I like the Netziv's explanation in his [Ha'amek Davar](https://www.sefaria.org/Haamek_Davar_on_Exodus.31.6.1?lang=bi) on the verse:

> ובלב כל חכם לב נתתי חכמה. בברכות דנ״ה אמרו שאין הקב״ה נותן חכמה אלא למי שיש בו חכמה מהאי קרא. והכי פי׳ הכתוב בדניאל יהב חכמתא לחכימין. והכונה בזה דשורש חכמה מתפרש על שתי הוראות. א׳ שכל וחריצות. ב׳ לימודיות ומדעים מה שהעלו אחרים כבר. וזהו פי׳ המקרא במשלי ראשית חכמה קנה חכמה ובכל קנינך קנה בינה. ראשית שכל האדם שיתנהג בלימודו. דמתחלה יקנה חכמת אחרים ואח״כ בכל קנינך קנה בינה להעלות דבר מדבר...
>
> I have also granted skill to all who are skillful: In [Brachos 55a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.55a.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) they (the sages) said that the Holy One Blessed be God only gave wisdom to those who had wisdom. (The Gemara asks) And thus the explanation is given that it is from Sefer Daniel ([2:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Daniel.2.21?lang=bi)) “He gives wisdom unto the wise..." And the intention in this is that the root of wisdom is explained by two teachings/manners: 1) logic and discernment 2) Learning and researching what others have already learned. And this is the explanation of the verse in Proverbs ([4:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.4.7?lang=bi)) The beginning of wisdom is—acquire wisdom; With all your acquisitions, acquire discernment. First comes the logical reasoning of the human as he behaves with learning - that he must first gain wisdom of others and afterwards he will be able to acquire wisdom learning one thing from another on his own intuition...

So the term is used specifically to connote the transmission of a specific skill to those who are already proficient.

Similarly, the [Rashbam](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.31.6?lang=bi&with=Haamek%20Davar&lang2=en) notes that Hashem had already equipped him with competent, skilled people to carry out the work. Likewise, this approach is adopted by [Rav Shimshon Raphael Hirsch](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/R._S.R._Hirsch/Shemot/31.6#m7e0n6) who notes that G-d only makes a person a vessel of Divine wisdom if they already possess and have developed the natural, human endowment of wisdom. (Refer also to the [Torah Temimah](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.31.6?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Torah_Temimah_on_Torah%2C_Exodus.31.6.2&lang2=bi))